# Count how many times two separate values in two separate columns there are

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am having an issue in Power BI, I am trying to count how many times a specific value, appears next to a specific date. However the value (which is text) and the date are ever changing so the code needs to be dynamic,

I have tried a few things and so far have the following:

```
`NrOfOccurrences = CALCULATE(
    count(Append1[Work Centre]),filter(Append1,Append1[Request Date] = earlier(Append1[Request Date])))`
```

But all that does is count how many times the date appears. Any Advice?

Example of what I'm trying to do "Amount" is what I'm trying to get

| Value | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 08/10/23 | 2 |
| AAA | 08/10/23 | 2 |
| AAA | 09/10/23 | 1 |
| BBB | 08/10/23 | 1 |
| CCC | 10/10/23 | 1 |
| DDD | 10/10/23 | 3 |
| DDD | 10/10/23 | 3 |
| DDD | 10/10/23 | 3 |

Comment: what about grouping by, that can solve your problem

Comment: Not entirely sure how grouping by would solve this problem, all data needs to remain in the same table as it all feeds graphs in the report section. 
I only need to figure out a code which will count how many times there is an A with a date. 

For Example:

A   08/10/23   2
A   08/10/23   2
A   09/10/23   1
B   08/10/23   1
C   10/10/23   1
D   10/10/23   3
D   10/10/23   3
D   10/10/23   3

Comment: I added an answer that can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table based on the existing one using this dax expression:

```
SUMMARIZE(Table
      , Table[Value]  
      , Table[Date]  
      , "Amount", COUNT(Table[[Work Centre]])  
      )
```

Comment: This almost looks like it would work, definitely on the right path, however now there is a new error message: 

"Expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple Columns cannot be converted to a scalar value"

Comment: I think that you are using SUMMARIZE in a measure, SUMMARIZE returns a table, try putting it in a table.

Comment: Yes, that all works & is showing in a new table, now I just need to append the tables, 

Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
numocc = 
COUNTX(
    FILTER(
        tbl,
        EARLIER(tbl[field1])=tbl[field1] && EARLIER(tbl[field2])=tbl[field2]
        ),
        tbl[field1]
    )
```

Comment: Tried this & adjusted fields to match, getting an error which states "DAX comparison doesn't support comparing values of type true/false with type date".